# Getting more column using foreign key possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC and I have been trying to create a school application in which I have these three classes:

```
public class student
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class subject
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int Math { get; set; }
    public int Computer { get; set; }
    public int Chemistry { get; set; }
}

public class result
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int studentId { get; set; }
    public int subjectId { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }

    public virtual student students { get; set; }
    public virtual subject subjects { get; set; }
}
```

I want to get all the properties of subject in result like math, computer, chemistry and so I can edit, create or delete them in result page.

Can somebody point me to any tutorial or help me with this?

Comment: Before you try creating an application, read a few tutorials on database normalization and then try to learn how to model a databse using code first approach. As it stands now, your code has too many flaws.

Answer (score 0):

A good starting point could be
[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/)